# Noises are measured over a bandwidth. Is 50Hz and 900Hz noise the same at 1kHz bandwidth?

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier, differential-amplifier, noise-spectral-density

They say noise is over a bandwidth. At a bandwidth of 1000Hz. Is the noise at 50Hz and 900Hz  similar? If yes. Please made a quick drawing how the noise at 50Hz and 900Hz look like roughly so I can visualize it, assuming the amplitude is 10uV and the noise is 2uV.

I'm asking this because in the following using the expensive gtec USBamp. The input is 10uV, 50Hz (no option to use higher frequency above it) and the butterworth filter is set to 1000Hz.  I want to know if 900Hz is resolvable given 50Hz is resolvable as they are both under the 1000Hz bandwidth. I need to know how the noise looks like at 50Hz vs 900Hz so please make a rough sketch.

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with [Nyquist Therom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) and [Fast Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform)?

Comment: yes I sample at 48kHz. my simulator only has 50Hz output. My real input is 10uV, 1000Hz. my question is with 1000Hz bandwidth chosen at amplifier. there is already much noise at 10uV 50Hz signal. so how do you compute the input frequency when the waveform can no longer be resolved using 1000Hz amplifier bandwidth.

Comment: How they "look" doesn't seem a very interesting question? -- I believe you can synthesize exactly what you describe in the tool you're currently using, and visually compare. (I'm not saying an answer cannot do this, or shouldn't; just, as I said: it doesn't seem very interesting.) What are you really after; are you trying to discriminate a tone or other signal from a noise floor? If so, what are the characteristics of those signals? What is the noise spectrum? Might a discussion of signal analysis, SNR, dynamic range, etc. be more helpful to you here?

Comment: My Netech simulator only has frequency choices of 0.1Hz, 2Hz, 5Hz, 50Hz, 60Hz only. I dont know how a frequency of 1000Hz would appear given the amplifier has 1000Hz bandwidth selected and ADC 48kHz in all cases in my setup.

Comment: @Jtl Maybe you ought to get a better simulator, then?

Comment: I think you have a major misunderstanding about what noise is and how measurement works. If there is one thing you can be absolutely certain of, it's that the time dimension is monotonic. There's no possibility for any noise to go back in time and combine with past noise, which is what it looks like you're asking about.

Comment: You said your amplifier passes up to at least 1000 Hz, 50 and 900 are both less than 1000, so at least as you have described it, both are equally passed by the system and there would be no difference between them.  Above 1000 Hz your filter will gradually attenuate the signal, so you'd eventually lose it in the noise.

Comment: I should say, I meant you showed a screenshot from Audacity -- you can generate tones and noise in that tool, mix them, and observe the result. || As for your question, you seem to be missing what the noise spectrum is, and perhaps missing the perspective of frequency vs. time domain (as mentioned earlier: the Fourier transform). Perhaps you should clarify what you are doing: what is your underlying task or problem, why do you need to know this, what are you doing with it?

Comment: I think I got what you guys mean.. that the sine wave shouldn't affect each other because each belongs to another time. So the answer is that if the amplifier bandwidth is 1000Hz. The sine waves noises at 50Hz and 900Hz are identical because making the current goes up and back faster as frequency goes up to 1000Hz doesn't create more noise? Right? pls say yes if true so I'm sure I got it right tnx.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve a signal, you must sample at least twice the frequency of the signal.  However, if you only sample at twice the input frequency then you would need to use the Fourier transform of the samples to interpolate and get smooth curves from it.  Therefore, one often samples much faster than twice the rate.  That may be 10X or 100X depending on how smooth you want things to be.

Noise power is often proportional to bandwidth.  And in that case, noise voltage would be proportional to the square root of the bandwidth (lowering bandwidth by 4X reduces noise voltage by 2X).  So, for low noise applications you want to limit the bandwidth.

For a low noise 50Hz sampling you may very well want to sample at 100Hz~200Hz and interpolate.

For a 10uV signal thermal noise can be significant so keep that in mind.

Comment: pls see latest edit. it's exactly what I wanted to know tnx